# Error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up :React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, android-emulator

I created new project with react-native but isn't working because my react-native can't running even though emulator is open .I looked stackOverflow for solutions then I try to fix the error but react native still can't running.

This is error:

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'D:\ReactNative\Boniki\android\local.properties'.

Comment: Please put your whole error log or attach screenshot here.